# Unstable WiFi on Ubuntu14.04.4 LTS (dual booted with windows7)

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, wireless, internet, network-manager

I dual booted my PC with Ubuntu 14.04.4(trusty), with Windows7 installed first. WiFi worked on Ubuntu for 2 weeks perfectly fine and then became unstable. It connects after rebooting for the first few minutes and then the signal shows connected but the pages wont load.Sometimes it does not detect any wifi signals.

Wifi on windows7 works perfectly fine. I use TrendNet wireless USB adapter to connect wifi to my desktop.

I am new to Ubuntu and tried the following solutions I found on internet.

1. I updated to network_manager_0.9.8.8-0.ubuntu7.3 and network_manager_gnome_0.9.8.8-0ubuntu4.4, the newest versions I could get.
2. Disabled firewall
3. Added BSSID
4. Ignored ipv6
5. Toggled ipv6 disable in about:config to true
6. Tried

   echo "options rtl8192cu swenc=1 fwlps=0 ips=0" | sudo tee   /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8192cu.conf

   echo 'KERNEL == "wlan0", RUN+=/sbin/iwconfig wlan0 txpower 18"' | sudo tee -a /etc/udev/rules.d/75-wlan.rules

Nothing worked.

I tried sudo apt-get update and upgrade, but since the internet does not stay long, the process gets halted without completing.

I am attaching my system wireless-info, gathered when connected to WiFi and disconnected (connected but no internet). Both are similar with few changes, but I do not want to take chances. 
[wireless-info-connected](http://paste.ubuntu.com/16639925/)

[wireless-info-disconnected](http://paste.ubuntu.com/16640030/)

I hope to get a solution to this problem from this forum. I am very new to Ubuntu and I hope I did not mess up my PC further by the above things I tried.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have read your system wireless information and in both cases your wireless hardware and drivers are working fine. In fact the problem is nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Your problem is congestion on the wireless channel you are using. You are using 2.4GHz channel 11. When you are getting a good connection there is only 1 other Access Point transmitting on that channel. When you are not getting a good connection there are 4 other Access Points contending for that channel.

Choose a better channel. Channels 3 and 7 are not being used at all.